# Node not being deleted from BST even if it is assigned null

Tags: actionscript-3, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference

I have constructed a BST in as3 which contains a function to delete a node from the tree which has the provided value.

Here is the code. Here pull actually means "delete". I am only giving the problematic code.

```
public function pull(k:int)
{
    //find the node in BST
    t = search(k);
    //if the node was found with value k
    if (t) 
    {
        //the node did not have any children
        if (t.none())
        {
            //simply set it to null
            t = null;
        }
        else if (t.one())
        {

        }
        else if (t.two())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have already inserted two values in tree 12 and 10.
the tree is like this

```
  12
 /
10
```

then I have called the function

```
 pull(10);
```

but when i try to trace(bst.root.leftChild) it still gives the output as

```
 [Object Node]
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with AS3, but I will attempt to answer this question.
Basically what you are doing when you do `t = search(k)` is that the search function returns a copy of the reference in `t`, in other words, `t` is set to refer to result of `search(k)`.

When you do `t = null`, you are doing nothing but removing that connection between `t` and the tree node which you want to delete. But that does not delete the node. It just sets `t` to refer to `null`.

Coming from C background, I will suggest 2 ways to solve it:

1. Use something like a pointer to pointer (if it exists in AS3, sorry I dont know about it).
2. Use the parent node of the desired node to delete it. For example if you want to delete a node `b` which is the left child of `a`, doing  `a.left = null` will delete the desired node as it effectively acts as a pointer to pointer.

I apologize for any factual mistakes in my answer, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you are correct, t = null; has no effect on the object itself it only affects the local variable holding a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an object to null is not an efficient way to delete it on the fly, in fact it will most likely keep existing for a while until it is eventually GC. But of course this can only happen if EVERY SINGLE reference of that object are nullified. Having one variable nullified will have no effect if that object is still referenced somewhere else.

So even when nullifying all references the object will keep existing for a while so the best way is to implement a method that will set the object to inactive to it can be skipped. The after that you can start removing all references to it.

The simple fact that you are tracing "trace(bst.root.leftChild)" means that the variable "leftChild" still has a reference to the node object, if you don't nullify that one then the object will still exist. If you don't nullify all references to that object then the object will keep existing.

Comment: giving an example would have been more helpful. Great explanation though.